# How to fix this error :"Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later"

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm trying to learn SWT, so I'm trying to create a simple hello world example

```
package test;



import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class nbstest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Display d = new Display();
        Shell s = new Shell(d);
        Text t = new Text(s, SWT.CENTER);
        t.setText("Hello World :) ");
        t.pack();

        s.pack();
        s.open();
        while (!s.isDisposed()) {
            if (!d.readAndDispatch())
                d.sleep();
            d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

But I get the folling warning:
Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later,

[image: warning]

and my helloWorld window do not show.
So how can I fix this?

Comment: I assume this is on a Mac? It sounds like you may be using a very old version of SWT. What version is it?

Comment: yes i m using mac , the version of swt that i used :4.5 .

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the `usrSpaceScaleFactor` message using SWT 4.5 or 4.6 on OS X 10.11.5.

Your `readAndDispatch` loop is incorrect which is stopping the shell from displaying. The `d.dispose` must be after the end of the loop:

```
while (!s.isDisposed()) {
   if (!d.readAndDispatch())
     d.sleep();
}

d.dispose();
```

Comment: Thannnks a lot , ça marche , j'ai le window affichée(malgré que le warning persitera ... )

Answer (score 0):

The warning message seem to be caused by this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386252

According to the bug report the problem will be solved in version 4.6 of SWT.